# Django - How to capture & record selected images

Tags: python, django, image

I am trying to filter out inappropriate images using a visual interface. Inappropriate images are subjective, which is why I want a user to select only the appropriate images (selecting multiple at a time) and press 'Finish' once selection is complete. The user's inputs should be stored in the database similar to this:

```
user_x = image1, image2, image4 ......
user_y = image6, image2, image3 ......
.
.
```

Here's what it currently look's like: [Image Filtration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkoXC.png)

I am a complete beginner to Django and I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**filter.html** *(Template to display images)*

```
   <div class="container-fluid my-container">

        {% filter_images_normal 3 as images %}

        <div class="row no-pad display-flex  my-row">
            {% for image in images %}
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col- my-col my-col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 my-col">
                    <input class="img-thumbnail" type="image" id="image" alt="Image" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{{ image }}">
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Finish</button>
    </div>
```

**filter_images.py** *(template tag to select distinct random images from folder)*

```
@register.simple_tag
def filter_images_normal(count=3):
    valid_extensions = ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif')
    rand_dir = '/static/app_filter/images/normal/'
    path = '/app_filter/static/app_filter/images/normal/'

    files = [f for f in os.listdir(settings.BASE_DIR + path)
             if f[f.rfind("."):] in valid_extensions]

    # print(random.sample(files, count))
    print(rand_dir)
    return [rand_dir + filename for filename in random.sample(files, count)]
```

**models.py**

```
class Normal(models.Model):
    appropriate_images_normal = models.TextField(max_length=30)
```

**views.py**

```
def pickfeel_filter_normal(request):
    return render(request, "app_filter/filter-normal.html")
```

Comment: an HTML <input type="image"> is a submit button with an image instead of a text. So it's not really useful for selecting multiple images, since clicking on one of them will submit the form. If you want the user to be able to select multiple images, you need to write some javascript to display what's selected and fill a hidden input field with the list of selected images (which is what will be submitted to your django view).

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you for you feedback, I will try exactly that. Will this approach still work if I display all images (unfiltered) using Django and then use javascript to select the images that are displayed. I'm also unsure about recording the input using Django. Once again, thank you for your help

Comment: yes, this will work. To record the selection, as I said, you need a form with a hidden input field that submits the list of images (just a hidden <select> with multiple=true), so you capture the selection of the user and on the Django side you just implement a MultipleChoiceField (in your form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this in a user friendly way is using javascript:

- on the Django side, it's a simple `Form` with a `MultipleChoiceField` where the choices need to reflect the images that you show to your user. The values need to be uniquely identifiable values so you know which image was selected and map it back to the actual file.
- Create the choices for the images in your view (not using a template tag) and pass the images in your context and as choices to your form field.
- In your template, render this form field as hidden. It'll be a `<select>` field with multiple set to true. Next to that, render your images using `<img>` tag instead of the `<input>` tag.
- Using javascript, detect whenever a user clicks on any of the images and do two things: 1. toggle a selection indicator to display to the user whether the image is selected or not. 2. Add/remove the image from the `<select>` options that are selected.

This way, when the form is submitted, the only field that matters will be the hidden field that you populated with javascript. If the field in your form is called `image_selection`, then `form.cleaned_data['image_selection']` will automatically be the list of images selected.

Comment: Great, thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it.